# Can I use kotlin-coroutines run a task periodically?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

It seems that I can use Code A to run a task periodically.

You know `soundDb()` can be fired every 100ms, it's just like to run periodically.

Is it a good way to use kotlin-coroutines run a task periodically?

**Code A**

```
fun calCurrentAsyn() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        var b = 0.0
        for (i in 1..5) {
            b = b + soundDb()
            delay(100)
        }
        b = b / 5.0
        myInfo.value = b.toString() + " OK Asyn  " + a++.toString()
    }
}

suspend fun soundDb(): Double {
    var k=0.0
    for (i in 1..500000000){
        k=k+i
    }
    return k
}
```

**Added Content:**

To Joffrey: Thanks!

1： I know that Code B is the better style, will the effect of execution be same between Code A and Code B ?

**Code B**

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    val b = computeCurrent()
    myInfo.value = "$b OK Asyn  ${a++}"
}

suspend fun computeCurrent(): Double {
    var b = 0.0
    repeat(5) {
        b += soundDb()
        delay(100)
    }
    return b / 5.0
}

suspend fun soundDb(): Double {
    var k=0.0
    for (i in 1..500000000){
        k=k+i
    }
    return k
}
```

2: I hope to get information regularly from a long running coroutine with a periodic task, how can I cancel the flow  `soundDbFlow().runningAverage()` ?

**Code C**

```
 viewModelScope.launch {
      soundDbFlow().runningAverage().collect {
        println("Average = $it") // do something with it
      }
   }
```

3: You know I can use `Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate` to get information regularly in background thread just like Code D,  which is the between `Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate` and `Flow` ?

**Code D**

```
   private fun startTimer() {
        timer = Timer()
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask {
            recordingTime = recordingTime + 1
            val temp = fromCountToTimeByInterval(recordingTime, 10)
            _timeElapse.postValue(temp) 
        }, 0, 10) 
    }

    private fun stopTimer() {
        timer.cancel()
        recordingTime = 0
        _timeElapse.postValue("00:00.00")
    }
```

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67135899/13546426) might help you.

Comment: Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54828055/5909412

Comment: The `soundDb()` function that you added seems really broken. It only returns one value (the sum of 1,2,3,...,500000000) at the end of the loop. Is this a real function? Or does this represent a function that returns a single value after some time (shown as a loop for the sake of the example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach (`launch` + loop) to repeat a task is not bad in itself, but the question is rather about how you want this coroutine to affect the rest of the application.

It's hard to tell whether this is an example for the sake of the question, or your actual code. If it is your actual code, your use case is not a classic "periodic task run":

- it has a fixed number of iterations
- it only has side effects at the end of the execution

This is an indication that it may make more sense to write this code as a suspend function instead:

```kotlin
suspend fun computeCurrent(): Double {
    var b = 0.0
    repeat(5) {
        b += soundDb()
        delay(100)
    }
    return b / 5.0
}
```

And then use it like this, to make it clearer where the results are used:

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch {
    val b = computeCurrent()
    myInfo.value = "$b OK Asyn  ${a++}"
}
```

Maybe you won't actually need to launch that coroutine in an async way (it probably depends on how you make other similar calls).

If you needed to get information regularly (not just at the end) from a long running coroutine with a periodic task, you might want to consider building a `Flow` instead and collecting it to apply the side-effects:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
import kotlin.time.Duration
import kotlin.time.Duration.Companion.milliseconds

fun soundDbFlow(period: Duration = 100.milliseconds) = flow {
    while (true) {
        emit(soundDb())
        delay(period)
    }
}

fun Flow<Double>.runningAverage(): Flow<Double> = flow {
    var valuesCount = 0
    var sum = 0.0
    collect { value ->
        sum += value
        valuesCount++
        emit(sum / valuesCount)
    }
}
```

And then the usage could be something like:

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch {
    soundDbFlow().take(5).runningAverage().collect {
        println("Average = $it") // do something with it
    }
}
```

---

About the amended question:

> I know that Code B is the better style, will the effect of execution be same between Code A and Code B ?

Code A and Code B behave the same. My point was indeed half about the style, because making it a simple suspend function makes it clear (to you and readers) that it only returns a single value. This seems to be a mistake that you make also in your newly added `soundDb()` function and I'm not sure it's clear to you that loops are not streams, and that you're only returning one value from those functions (not updating anything several times).

The other half of my point was that, since it's only a single value that you updated, it may not even need to be run in a long-running coroutine. You might integrate it with other pieces of suspending code where needed.

> how can I cancel the flow soundDbFlow().runningAverage() ?

The flow is automatically canceled if the collecting coroutine is cancelled (either via the job you `launch`ed or by cancelling the whole viewModelScope - which happens automatically when the component is not needed). The flow is also cancelled if you use terminal operators that end the collection early, such as `first()`, `takeWhile()`, `take(n).collect { .. }`, etc.

> You know I can use Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate to get information regularly in background thread just like Code D, which is the between Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate and Flow ?

It's up to you honestly. If you're using coroutines already, I'd personally favor the flow approach. `scheduleAtFixedRate` will not be integrated with structured concurrency and will require manual management of the cancellation.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: Thank you very much,  how can I cancel the flow `soundDbFlow().runningAverage()` by myself instead of automatically by system?

Comment: The call to `launch` returns a `Job` instance, so you can use `job.cancel()` if you want to manually handle it. However, it should be uncommon to need that

Comment: Thanks! But `fun Flow<Double>.runningAverage(): Flow<Double> = flow` is not correct, it displays `Type mismatch.Required:FlowCollector<Double> Found:([ERROR :  ]) → TypeVariable(_L)` .

Comment: @HelloCW it might be something else, because this works fine: https://pl.kotl.in/WihgA3vFJ Maybe create another question with your actual code and the error, so we can have more context to help figure out the problem