# Android CountDownTimer with Kotlin Flows

Tags: android, countdowntimer, kotlin-flow

I'm a bit stuck while implementing **Android Timer Use Case** which is supposed to return a Kotlin flow.

The `invoke()` function of the use case takes ***LocalDateTime*** and should return `Flow<String>` with each tick.

This is how I have structured my use case code:

```
class CountDownUseCase {

    operator fun invoke(launchDate: LocalDateTime): Flow<String> {
        ...
     override fun onTick(millscUntilFinish: Long) {

         //getting error here 
         emit(remaingTimeString)    }
     override fun onFinish() {...   }
    }
```

This is the error that I'm getting on `emit()` - *Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body*

[image]

This is the full code for a better picture

```
operator fun invoke(launchDate: LocalDateTime): Flow<String> =
        flow {
            var remainingTimeString: String = ""
            val currentDateTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

            //convert LocalDateTime to millis
            val zdt = launchDate.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            val futureLaunchDate = zdt.toInstant()
                    .toEpochMilli()
            val timeDifference = futureLaunchDate - currentDateTime

            val countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(timeDifference, 1000) {
                override fun onTick(millscUntilFinish: Long) {
                    remainingTimeString = """
                   
                   ${TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millscUntilFinish)}:
                   ${TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millscUntilFinish) % 24}: 
                   ${TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millscUntilFinish) % 60}:
                   ${TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millscUntilFinish) % 60}
                """.trimIndent()

                    emit(remainingTimeString)
                }
```

I have looked around but can't find a way to emit a flow with each timer tick.

I will appreciate any help to go about returning a flow every time `onTick()` override function is called.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to achieve this is to wrap the emit call with the **suspend** lambda function:

```
suspend {
  emit(remainingTimeString)
}
```

But I won't recommend it, because using `CountDownTimer` should be replaced with a way more admirable logic, that can fit directly without using "stitches" into coroutines scope. I don't recommend it, because it has to be correctly stopped and cleaned, otherwise, it can cause memory issues (leaks).

For example, take a look at this sample here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63939980/1537916

or this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54828055/1537916

Comment: Nice try, thanks too for the leak disclaimer, I will deeply have a look at the resources you have provided but as you have rightly pointed out `CountDownTimer` will need something cleaner and elegant, I will post it should I hack it.

Answer (score 1):

Example of Android `CountDownTimer` with `callbackFlow`

```kotlin
class CountDownTimerWrapper(total: Long, interval: Long, onFinish: () -> Unit) {
    private lateinit var countDownTimer: CountDownTimer

    val flow: Flow<Long> = callbackFlow {
        countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(total, interval) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                trySend(millisUntilFinished)
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                onFinish()
            }
        }

        awaitClose { countDownTimer.cancel() }
    }

    fun start() {
        countDownTimer.start()
    }
}
```